# Magic date in seconds

Tags: php

Code work great until 29.10.2017 Any suggestions ?

```
$blabla="29.10.2017"; // problem with this date 
$blabla = strtotime($blabla); 
$blabla=date('d.m.Y',($blabla)); 
echo $blabla."<br />"; 
$blabla = strtotime($blabla); 
$blabla=$blabla+86400+86400; // only +2 days works  
$blabla=date('d.m.Y',($blabla)); 
echo $blabla."  <br />";
```

Comment: Just to mention, the first `echo $blabla.`... line has the wrong kind of quote starting the string. I assume this isn't the case in your actual code, else it shouldn't work at all.

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe it's the 'wrong' quote you are using at line 4 as @cHao already mentioned

Comment: I doubt *"Code work great until..."* if the bad quotes were in the actual code

Comment: How exactly does this *"not work"* on / after 29.10.2017?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because there is switch from daylight saving time to standard time at that day

```
strtotime('+ 2 days',$yourTime);
```

should work better at this case

Comment: Entirely depends on OP's configured timezone but you're probably correct :)